# Как сделать рамку c padding вокруг "carosel-элементов" в Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

В данном коде реализуется карусель. Но никак правильно не получается отобразить рамку с `padding`. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.img_dost_border {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row places" v-show="cafedral">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <h5>Кафедральный собор(архитектура, история, искусство)
      <a href="https://2gis.ru/kaliningrad/firm/5630027815206179" class="nav_a2"><img src="images/2gis.png" alt="" height="15px" width="35px" style="margin-left: 1px;"></a>
    </h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active ">
          <img src="images/test.jpg" class="d-block img_dost img_dost_border " alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="images/kafedralnyj-sobor_2.jpg" class="d-block img_dost img_dost_border" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <img src="images/kafedralnyj-sobor_3.jpg" class="d-block img_dost img_dost_border" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                                    <img src="images/left-arrow.svg" width="30px">
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </span>
      <span class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="" data-slide="next">
                                                    <img src="images/arrow-point-to-right.svg" width="30px">
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="col-sm-6 text_dost2">
    Кафедральный собор – это один из символов Калининграда. Возраст сооружения насчитывает около 700 лет (с 1333 года). Сейчас собор используется как музей, где можно детально изучить историю Кенигсберга. Обязательно узнайте о графике органных концертов –
    все посетившие туристы очень хорошо отзываются и выражают полнейший восторг. Цена посещения: 250 рублей для взрослого, 150 рублей органный концерт. Рядом с Кафедральным собором начинаются экскурсии на катерах по реке Преголя.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задавайте обводку и отступы всей карусели, а не картинке. + Картинку сделайте адаптивной - `img-fluid`  :

```css
.carousel {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row places" v-show="cafedral">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <h5>Кафедральный собор(архитектура, история, искусство)
        <a href="https://2gis.ru/kaliningrad/firm/5630027815206179" class="nav_a2"><img src="images/2gis.png" alt="" height="15px" width="35px" style="margin-left: 1px;"></a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active ">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558236588-e3bc00ea77fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" class="d-block img_dost img_dost_border img-fluid " alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item ">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558210834-473f430c09ac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" class="d-block img_dost img_dost_border img-fluid" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item ">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558254026-f13859e884d8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" class="d-block img_dost img_dost_border img-fluid" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <img src="images/left-arrow.svg" width="30px">
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </span>
        <span class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="" data-slide="next">
         <img src="images/arrow-point-to-right.svg" width="30px">
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="col-sm-6 text_dost2">
      Кафедральный собор – это один из символов Калининграда. Возраст сооружения насчитывает около 700 лет (с 1333 года). Сейчас собор используется как музей, где можно детально изучить историю Кенигсберга. Обязательно узнайте о графике органных концертов –
      все посетившие туристы очень хорошо отзываются и выражают полнейший восторг. Цена посещения: 250 рублей для взрослого, 150 рублей органный концерт. Рядом с Кафедральным собором начинаются экскурсии на катерах по реке Преголя.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```